# How to override frequency in Bloomberg BDS request?

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I am using the Bloomberg Excel add-on to retrieve bulk history data for some mutual funds. Specifically, I need to get their dividend history including dividend income, short term capital gains, long term capital gains, etc. I'll list the "dividend frequency" and "dividend type" below that I need.

For the most part, this formula works just fine:

```
=BDS("FILDX US Equity", "DVD_HIST_ALL", "DVD_START_DT=20080501", "DVD_END_DT=20180301", "Headers=True")
```

This provides me with all of the data I need for symbol `"FILDX US Equity"` and it respects the start and end dates.

However, for some symbols I only get about the last 12 month's worth of dividend data returned. Based on my research, if the symbol's dividend history includes a `"Dividend Type"` of `"Daily Accrual"` I only get 12 months of data. It does NOT respect my start and end date overrides.

An example would be for symbol `"WAPAX US Equity"`. This symbol has been around for many years (and paying dividends) but BB is only returning the last year's data.

```
=BDS("WAPAX US Equity", "DVD_HIST_ALL", "DVD_START_DT=20080501", "DVD_END_DT=20180301", "Headers=True")
```

So, how do I rewrite the `BDS` formula so that I can get its ENTIRE dividend history? Do I need to override the "frequency" or "type" fields to filter out (or filter in) certain things? Is there a certain `periodicityAdjustment` or similar that I need?

Here are the frequencies and types I wish to have:

```
frequency => None, Monthly, Quarter, Semi-Anl, Annual, Irreg
type => Income, Short Term Cap Gain, Long Term Cap Gain, Omitted, Special Cash
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: @assylias The terminal is sitting on a trader's desk 1000 miles away. I program the spreadsheets in my office and send them to the trader for his use. When they don't work, he just kicks it back. He does NOT cooperate or help me with troubleshooting, nor will he look anything up on the terminal for me. And no one is going to fly me out there to use the terminal directly. I'm between a rock and a hard place. Help!

Comment: Looking at the description of the field on Bloomberg: "The field is limited to returning the most recent 275 records within the date range provided.". So you'll need to play with the start and end date to retrieve more history.

Comment: There is no way to filter out the daily events in the BDS formula, you have to do it in Excel.

Comment: Thank you, @assylias, that is helpful. I'll put together a sheet that repeats the `BDS` formula every 275 rows ("Headers=False") and reference the prior row's date. When I get it working, I'll "answer" my own question here and post the result.

Comment: Sounds like a plan